# How to show string of array in the first column of primeng table in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, multidimensional-array, angular8, primeng

I have a string of array and I want to display that array in first column of the table like this

```
    c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6
    d1 -  -  -  -  -
    d2 -  -  -  -  -
    d3 -  -  -  -  -
    d4 -  -  -  -  -
```

the string of array is like this

```
    data: string[] = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4',];
```

so here is my html code

```html
<p-table [columns]="panel.headers" [value]="panel.data">
   <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
      <tr *ngFor="let headerRow of panel.headers">
       <th *ngFor="let col of headerRow.cols" [attr.colspan]="col.colspan"
       [attr.rowspan]="col.rowspan">
           {{col.label}}
       </th>
     </tr>
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-row>
    <tr>
     <td *ngFor="let col of panel.headers[panel.headers.length-1].cols"
       class="{{row[col.dataClasses]}}">
       {{row[col.valueField]}}
     </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

See the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabledynamic-demo-h58rsj
in this example, I want to print tiers in the first column.
please help to solve this..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add the column at the beginning:

```
 <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-row>
      <tr>
       <td>my array goes here</td>
       <td *ngFor="let col of panel.headers[panel.headers.length-1].cols"
         class="{{row[col.dataClasses]}}">
         {{row[col.valueField]}}
       </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
```

And in your header:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>

        <tr *ngFor="let headerRow of panel.headers">
        <th></th>
         <th *ngFor="let col of headerRow.cols" [attr.colspan]="col.colspan"
         [attr.rowspan]="col.rowspan">
             {{col.label}}
         </th>
       </tr>
     </ng-template>
```

Comment: I want this array in the c1 column not in a separate header. I can't add another header column or body column this..
Can u give me solution in component.ts
like using some logic and push the data into that column

Comment: can you set up an stackblitz demo of you problem?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabledynamic-demo-h58rsj

I want to print that tiers array in the upm column